# How to create beautiful lists with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, html-lists

I would like to know if it is possible to render beautiful lists like the ones demonstrated here http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-simple-and-practical-css-list-styles-you-can-copy-and-paste/ using wordpress and the tinymce editor and if it is possible please show me and the rest of the world how.

Content managers should focus on writing content, not markup!

Ideally I would have a a button which creates a list from the highlighted rows of text as per the list buttons that are already there in TinyMCE editor but with one or two subtle differences, they add in a span tag in between the li tags etc?

Hoping someone out there can help!

Answer (score 1):

for now I have made a very simple, non scale-able hack but which is not ideal, but for anyone interested in achieving a similar result this is what I did.

In the file responsible for the output, in my case single.php  I simple searched the output variable for the li tags and replaced them with LIs and spans using str_replace.

Here is the code

```
echo str_replace("<ul>","<ul class=\"num\">",str_replace("</li>","</span></li>",str_replace("<li>","<li><span>",$content)));
```